# Error on converting the buffer into the video in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding

I want to make buffer from the `mp4 video` and then again convert that buffer into the video.

I am generating buffer as

```
const buffer = Buffer.from("Cat.mp4");
console.log(buffer);
```

I am getting output `<Buffer 43 61 74 2e 6d 70 34>`

Now I am again converting that buffer into video

```
fs.writeFile("test.mp4", buffer, 'binary',function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Done!");
    }
});
```

It is giving the output `Done!` But when I am trying to play that video it is giving an error `Could not determine the stream`.

I don't know if I am wrong in converting buffer or in converting video.

Please, someone, help me.

Answer (score 3):

You're actually converting the string `"Cat.mp4"` into a buffer:

```
//<Buffer 43 61 74 2e 6d 70 34>
//        C  a  t  .  m  p  4
```

Try using:

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('Cat.mp4', (err, buffer) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('do we have a buffer?', buffer instanceof Buffer)
});
```

As per [its documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback):

> If no encoding is specified, then the raw buffer is returned.

Comment: Gives an error `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Cat.mp4'`

Comment: Well then, `Cat.mp4` doesn't exist there, right? ;)

Comment: No, it exists, but maybe it is searching for any directory. I think. because `Cat.mp4` and `app.js` are on same folder.

Comment: This is weird... Try `./Cat.mp4` first (although not a chance IMO), then try using built-in `path` module: `path.join(__dirname, 'Cat.mp4')`. Also, are you sure about the case? (Capital 'C', lower case extension.)